# Sort a view by price using commerce price?

Tags: commerce

I have a custom view (created with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)) that is working fine. But when I add a price field to it and sort the view with same field in descending or ascending order, it is not working.

Any suggestions to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps and share the output:

1. Create a views with the same content type in which the field exists from which you need to filter easily with "filter section" in views.
2. Select the same field of content which you want to filter.
3. Select the same fields in filter with sorting order "ASC" or "DESC".

Mention please use [Commerce Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_views_display) plugin for the same.

Thanks.